# How to save users log in the server in react?

Tags: reactjs, logging, log-level

I want to save users' logs to my own server. How can I do that?
And also can I get full stacktrace like development server in the production? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to explicitly capture and send them over the network. That's too much to cover in an SO question.

Comment: Does this doc help? [Measure and analyze the performance of your application using different metrics.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/measuring-performance/)